# Check if date is in the past without submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, date

I have this code that I want to check if a date is in the past. I want to check it as soon as the date is entered, before form submission.

```
<input id="datepicker" onchange="checkDate()" required class="datepicker-input" type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >

<script type="text/javascript">
 function checkDate() {
   var selectedDate = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
   var now = new Date();
   if (selectedDate < now) {
    alert("Date must be in the future");
   }
 }
</script>
```

This does not work, if I enter a date in the past (e.g. 2014-12-03) it does not display the alert.

Comment: because a string is not a date.

Comment: The input is in this format though yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: ANd that is still a string, not a date. The input value is not a Date Object.

Comment: oh ok. how can i convert it?

Comment: Have you considered timezones, btw or just that the fact that the user can change their OS clock for any reason ? :)

Comment: I have server side validation already implemented. But I want realtime validation as well @ThongKuah

Comment: Any have idea about this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062690/how-to-disable-select-previous-date-in-datepicker-js/42062836?noredirect=1#comment71298931_42062836

Answer (score 20, accepted):

All you need to do is convert the string produced by the `<input>` into a Date using the Date constructor `new Date("2014-06-12")`

```js
 function checkDate() {
   var selectedText = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
   var selectedDate = new Date(selectedText);
   var now = new Date();
   if (selectedDate < now) {
    alert("Date must be in the future");
   }
 }
```

```html
<input id="datepicker" onchange="checkDate()" required class="datepicker-input" type="date" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >
```

Comment: It's not working. But it seems the issue is something else. Even if I do this:
 $("#datepicker").change(function() {
  alert( "test" );
});
the alert doesn't show

Comment: It's working for me? Try typing 2014-06-12 into the box and pressing enter (you need to press enter or change focus of the control to trigger the onchange event)

Comment: ah ok. I removed the date picker plugin and it worked. How can I make it work using the date picker plugin

Comment: If you want to use a date picker plugin, use jQuery UI's one, and then you can set minDate and maxDate instead of your own validation function. See [this example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: add now.setHours(0,0,0,0); so that you will not get alert for today date

Answer (score 1):

The `date()` function returns a string. Try converting both dates to integers first using the `Date.parse()` function:

```html
<input id="datepicker" onchange="checkDate()" required class="datepicker-input" type="text" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" >

<script type="text/javascript">
   function checkDate() {
       var selectedDate = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
       var now = new Date();
       var dt1 = Date.parse(now),
       dt2 = Date.parse(selectedDate);
       if (dt2 < dt1) {
            alert("Date must be in the future");
       }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: It seems the issue is something else, because even if I do this: $("#datepicker").change(function() { alert( "test" ); }); 
the alert doesn't show

Comment: I'll suggest you look at your browser's console; you might have an error elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

For those who use type="date" (introduced with HTML5) instead of type="text", it can be done this way:

```
 function checkDate() {
   var date = this.value;
   if(date.valueAsDate <= new Date()) {
       //Date in the past
   } else {
       //Date in the future
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is really close, try this instead:

```
var selectedDate = $('#datepicker').datepicker('getDate');
var now = new Date();
if (selectedDate < now) {
  // selected date is in the past
}
```

Comment: Please try to compare date by using getTime function...

if (selectedDate.getTime() < now.getTime()) {
    ...
}

Comment: As far as I know, that solution depends on having jQuery UI installed. It's basically converting your input field to a datepicker widget. It will work, but it's totally unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mine function working ...

```
function check_not_past_date_time(enter_date) {
    var a =new Date(enter_date);
    var now =new Date();
    if(a>now){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
_isDate1LowerThanDate2(date1, date2) {
    return new Date(date1) < new Date(date2);
  }
```

Comment: Explain why you think such comparison of objects will work. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Before comparing dates, they should be set to 0 hours. This would ensure difference between them is in multiples of 1 day.

```
const isPastDate = (date) => {
    const specificDate = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    const today = new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return specificDate < today;
}

console.log(isPastDate("2021-08-10T23:59:00"));
```