# how to disable select previous date in datepicker JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-datepicker

My Frondend Code

```
<div class="col-md-4">DisablePast Date</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input class="form-control datepicker" type='date' id="date">
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
$("#date").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
```

});

Comment: `minDate:0 ` disables previous dates. What do you want?

Comment: It's not work brother

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: no. when i select past date. it's selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Date Picker - disable past dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356358/jquery-date-picker-disable-past-dates)

Comment: Okay, good, can you tell me how can we validate from server side. It's user side. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
var dateToday = new Date();
$(function () {
    $("#date").datepicker({ minDate: dateToday })
});

<div class="col-md-8">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
    <input class="form-control datepicker" type='date' name="date" id="date">
    </form>
</div>
```

php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
        //do processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, good, can you tell me how can we validate from server side. It's user side. thanks in advance

Comment: Cool :) what server side programming language you using?

Comment: I am using Php, can we validate in JS. when user select previous date after that submit button we alert them select "select date after today" . :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714469/check-if-date-is-in-the-past-without-submitting-form

I got another answer too... and happy from your side..

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062690/how-to-disable-select-previous-date-in-datepicker-js/42062836?noredirect=1#comment71298931_42062836

any about this question @Web Dev Guy